# Combining dynamic arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am struggling with combining these 2 arrays a while now. Can someone help me what to use?

```
Array
(
  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1-1
        [1] => 1-2
        [2] => 1-1
        [3] => 1-2
        [4] => 1-1
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3-3
        [1] => 3-3
        [2] => 3-4
        [3] => 3-4
        [4] => 3-3
    )
)



Array[1] key [0] => 1-1 needs to combine with
Array[3] key [0] => 3-3
Array[1] key [1] => 1-2 needs to combine with
Array[3] key [1] => 3-3
```

Result would be: 1-1,3-3 and 1-2,3-3

Please note that the keys from the first array [1] and [3] can be dynamic.

I did this:

```
print_r(array_merge_recursive($optionWithValue[1], $optionWithValue[3]));
```

But now i have the 1 and 3 hardcoded which can change and i ended up with:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1-1
  [1] => 1-2
  [2] => 1-1
  [3] => 1-2
  [4] => 1-1
  [5] => 3-3
  [6] => 3-3
  [7] => 3-4
  [8] => 3-4
  [9] => 3-3
)
```

So that's also not what i need

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you trying to have unique values only and then merge the 2? where's is your merging code?

Comment: `1-1,3-3` as in `"1-1,3-3"`, or an array containing both? Either way, please share your attempts.

Comment: I added an example in my main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys of the arrays in the array are the same, you might use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$arrays = [
    [
        "1-1",
        "1-2",
        "1-1",
        "1-2",
        "1-1",
    ],
    [
        "3-3",
        "3-3",
        "3-4",
        "3-4",
        "3-3",
    ],
];
$first = array_shift($arrays);
$res = array_reduce($arrays, function($carry, $item){
   foreach($item as $key => $value)  {
       $carry[$key] = $carry[$key] . "," . $value;
   }
   return $carry;
}, $first);

print_r($res);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1-1,3-3
    [1] => 1-2,3-3
    [2] => 1-1,3-4
    [3] => 1-2,3-4
    [4] => 1-1,3-3
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/U0JKU)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i needed, i tested it right away and it works :D